# swift for-in loop in playground just counts loops, does not print

Tags: xcode, swift, enums, enumerator

Just getting started with Swift, looking at [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)), it has this code:

> // Define a dictionary with four items:
>   // Each item has a person's name and age
>   let people = ["Anna": 67, "Beto": 8, "Jack": 33, "Sam": 25]
>
> // Now we use Swift's flexible enumerator system
>   // to extract both values in a single loop
>   for (name, age) in people {
>    print("\(name) is \(age) years old.")
>   }

Putting this into a playground in XCode, I expected this to see this:

`Anna is 67 years old.`
`Beto is 8 years old.`

etc.

Instead, in the right-hand panel, it just shows this:

`(4 times)`

There is a button over on the far right, beyond the `(4 times)` which, when I click it, causes `Jack is 33 years old.` to display within the loop. (See screen shot below.) Click the button again, and that disappears.  Can anyone help me understand the logic behind all this?

[image: for-in mystery]

Comment: The printed lines are visible in the Debug Area (⇧⌘Y)

Comment: Swift uses `\()` to print a number value in a string output, for example: `print("This is a string \(number). )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small issue in your code you should include a parameter "\(name)" not (name) in order to print it. so you should use like this

```
for (name, age) in people {
    print("\(name) is \(age) years old.")
}
```

If you want to show all the value as you asked on question just follow these steps :-

```
**Step 1**
```

Clicks the + sign right corner.Then it shows latest value.
[image]

**Step 2**

If you want to show all the values clicks the recent value and right click and choose value history

[image]

**Step 3**

Then you can see the all values.

[image]

Comment: The backslash was in my code but "disappeared" in the stackoverflow markdown.  I got it to appear by doubling the backslash: \\                                          Both this answer and the next one were useful and correct.  Wish I could mark both as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

what you are missing is called String interpolation. So you for printing a value of a variable/constant by concatinating it with string you have to do it like this.

```
print("\(name) is \(age) years old.")
```

Secondly you have to press (⇧⌘Y) in order to see the output in debuging area

[image]